# @PostPersist doesn't save the Audit Record to the DB

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, openjpa, apache-karaf

I have a Listener with @PostPersist method called "doAudit" to audit create action.On debugging I see This method gets called and Audit record is created on JAVA side. But when I verify the DB I don't see the record.

```
public class AuditListener {
    @PostPersist
    public void doAudit(Object object) {
        AuditDao auditManager = AuditDaoImpl.getInstance();
        auditManager.logEvent("create", object);
    }
}

public interface AuditDao {
    @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public AuditEntity logEvent(String action, Object object);
}

@Component
public class AuditDaoImpl implements AuditDao {

    private static AuditDaoImpl me;

    public AuditDaoImpl() {
        me = this;
    }

    public static AuditDaoImpl getInstance() {
        return me;
    }

    @Autowired
    private AuditDao dao;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public AuditEntity logEvent(String action, Object object) {

        AuditEntity act = new AuditEntity();
        act.setAction(action);
        act.setObject(object);

        dao.create(act);
        return act;
    }
}
```

I am using Open JPA 2.0 as for my ORM. Deployed on karaf container. I am using Postgres SQL as my backend.

Answer (score 0):

Add a debug breakpoint and check if the current stack-trace contains the [TransactionInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor.html). If there's no such entry, the Spring transaction management is not properly configured and your DAOs don't use transactions at all.

JPA allows you to run queries without configuring transactions explicitly. For saving data, transactions are mandatory.

Comment: I will debug and look for TransactionInterceptor. One interesting thing is when I change PostPersist to PrePersist the Audit record is saved to DB, but I want it to work on PostPersist. Thanks